# How should I call a base class constructor with a class derived from a generic base class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class `Grid` which contains `Cell`s. My plan is to create several derived classes for `Grid` (TriangleGrid, SquareGrid, HexGrid) and `Cell` (TriangleCell, SquareCell, HexCell). Each `Grid` will have a `GetAdjacentCells` method.

```
abstract public class Grid<T> where T:Cell {
  protected T[,] cells_;
  abstract public List<T> GetAdjacentCells(T cell);
}

abstract public class Cell {
  protected Grid<Cell> grid_;
  public Cell(Grid<Cell> grid, int x, int y) {
    grid_ = grid;
  }
}
```

The `HexGrid` derived classes:

```
public class HexGrid : Grid<HexCell> {}
```

and

```
public class HexCell : Cell {
  public HexCell(HexGrid grid, int x, int y)
      : base(grid, x, y) { // compilation error here!
  }
}
```

Each `Cell` has a reference to its `Grid`, which is passed in through the `Cell` constructor. The issue I am facing is an error on the `HexCell` constructors call to `base` which says:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'HexGrid' to 'Grid<Cell>'
```

`HexGrid` is a `Grid<HexCell>` and `HexCell` is derived from `Cell` so it seems like it should work.

I tried making `Grid` and `Cell` abstract. I tried casting the `grid` argument to `(Grid<Cell>)` which produced an error too.
Any suggestions would great. Thanks!

Comment: Please follow this sites tagging guidelines and do not place tags in your question titles. I note that you have yet to take the [tour], so I strongly recommend you do that in order to learn how to best utilise the site.

Comment: @Llama It was very tough crafting the title for this question (it didn't use tags but what I had was tough to follow). I have updated it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You had written _"C# How ...."_ (C# being considered a "tag"). I do agree that your edit has made your title vastly better.

Comment: Interesting problem. I suspect you need to use a generic argument to the `Cell` class as well, but since they depend on each other, that causes some weird circular dependencies on the type parameters. I haven't found the correct solution yet.

Comment: The cell appars missing in detail, but essentially the important part is if You control it, can You change that class too?

Comment: Just because two types exhibit a particular inheritance relationship, that *doesn't* mean that a generic type parameterised by those two types exhibits the same inheritance relationship. A `Grid<HexCell>` is *not* derived from `Grid<Cell>`.

Comment: @T. Nielsen I completely control all classes in this project.

Comment: Do the `Cell` / `HexCell` instances really need to know which `Grid` / `HexGrid` instance they are part of? I'd understand that dependency if it was the responsibility of the `Cell` to work out what its neighbouring `Cell`s are, but you've made `GetAdjacentCells` a method of the `Grid` class, which suggests to me that it's up to the `Grid` to work out which cells are adjacent, therefore the `Cell` instances don't need to know about each other, nor about the `Grid` that they're part of.

Comment: "My plan is to create several derived classes for Grid (TriangleGrid, SquareGrid, HexGrid) and Cell (TriangleCell, SquareCell, HexCell)." I don't understand how generics are supposed to be useful here. Is it supposed to be useful - or even *meaningful* - to mix the types, and instantiate e.g. a `SquareGrid<HexCell>`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few approaches and failed. But then: Why do we need generics in this case at all? Consider this idea:

```cs
abstract public class Grid
{
    protected Cell[,] cells_;
    abstract public List<Cell> GetAdjacentCells(Cell cell);
}

abstract public class Cell
{
    protected Grid grid_;
    public Cell(Grid grid, int x, int y)
    {
        grid_ = grid;
    }
}

public class HexGrid : Grid
{
    public override List<Cell> GetAdjacentCells(Cell cell)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There's nothing that needs to be generic here.

Comment: It's plausible that each type of `Grid` needs its own corresponding type of `Cell`. But those could instead be, for example, inner classes that also inherit from the base `Cell`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, and it depends on how visible the `Cell` generally needs to be. I would even consider making the `Cell` an internal class of the Grid, if possible.

Comment: @PMF yes well if there are no different types of grids planned, I agree. when generics makes sense it is presuming that more than one type of grid is to be supported.
Personally I saw the problem as being to make the inheritance work, not why it is needed, but indeed there is a risk we're looking into an overengineered solution from get go, only author can reveal.

Comment: @T.Nielsen Different grid types here are implemented via inheritance. A generic parameter would IMHO make sense when the _content_ of the grid cells shall change, so when the cells are containers for some object.

Comment: @PMF exactly. And i suppose with the HexGrid to be a grid containing i suppose Hexadecimal values, perhaps there is plan for another type of grid one containing for instance DecGrid decimals or PctGrid for Percentage type cells. Which i agree is the only when it would make sense (and which i suspect is wanted), otherwise your non generic can solve the problem just fine.

Comment: @T.Nielsen No, I think the OP was talking about Hexagonal Grids and Square Grids and the like. So it's the shape of the Cells, not their content.

Answer (score 0):

Since You have control over the cell too, make it be implementing an interface and then use that as 'contract' this way all derived ones or usages can be of this and you just have to promote necessary stuff to the interface though.

```
public interface ICell
{
    
}

abstract public class Grid<T> where T : ICell
{
    protected T[,] cells_;
    abstract public List<T> GetAdjacentCells(T cell);
}

abstract public class Cell : ICell
{
    protected Grid<ICell> grid_;
    public Cell(Grid<ICell> grid, int x, int y)
    {
        grid_ = grid;
    }
}

public class HexGrid : Grid<ICell>
{
    public override List<ICell> GetAdjacentCells(ICell cell)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class HexCell : Cell
{
    public HexCell(HexGrid grid, int x, int y)
        : base(grid, x, y)
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using abstract classes unless you have a good reason to and/ or want to prevent them from being instantiated for some reason.